# Как сделать выборку всех значений что находятся внутри RegEx, и вставить в src по отдельности. У меня берет только первое совпадение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
str = ";happy;;cry;"

str= str.replace(/;([\s\S]*);/g, '<img src="storage/chat/smiles/$1"style="display: inline;" alt="smile"/>');
```

В результате должна получиться str с двумя img внутри и правильным src

Comment: Я понимаю что то мне нужно что вместо '$1' указать , $& не работает

Comment: Может, `/;([^;]*);/g`?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, не помогло к сожалению

Comment: Результат вы какой ожидаете? `";happy;;cry;".replace(/;([^;]+);/g, '<img src="storage/chat/smiles/$1" style="display: inline;" alt="smile"/>');` вроде работает, как надо, результат  -  `<img src="storage/chat/smiles/happy" style="display: inline;" alt="smile"/><img src="storage/chat/smiles/cry" style="display: inline;" alt="smile"/>`

Comment: Да именно такой ) только мне возвращает только один  img - первый.

Comment: Прошу прощения, все работает!!! Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищите текст между двумя соседними одинаковыми символами. В данном случае можно воспользоваться *исключающим символьным классом*:

```
/;([^;]*);/g
```

- `;` - точка с запятой
- `([^;]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более символов, отличных от точки с запятой
- `;` - точка с запятой.

Пример работы кода на JS:

```js
console.log(
   ";happy;;cry;".replace(
      /;([^;]+);/g, 
      '<img src="storage/chat/smiles/$1" style="display: inline;" alt="smile"/>'
   )
)
```